# How to lnsert Centered Vertical Dots in a Table with Multiply lmages to Express Omit

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

I have a question about vertical dots, generally, I'm now using `\vdot` in a table to express omit, but I want them to be centralized to express omit, the current codes are shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{Text.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l Sl X }
    \toprule
        Iterations & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0     & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & Text is always being here\\
        32    & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & Text \\ 
        64    & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & Text \\
        128   & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & Text \\
        192   & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & Text \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        3200  & $\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{000000.png}$ & Text \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab4}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

I had tried to use `\usepackage{mathtools}` but it seems not to work, is there anyone familiar with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make a *compilable* [mre], including the necessary packages and a documentclass

Comment: if you want to use a math command, you need to make sure that you are in math mode and not in a normal left aligned column

Comment: Also why on earth do you put your images in math mode in a siunitx column????

Comment: and please count your columns. You specify 4. but then only give 3 columns

Comment: Got it, I will modify it now!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry about the late reply, I had modified it but I'm not sure whether all is correct, I just learn LaTex for several days and has no conception of siunitx column, this table is actually modified based on many people's help and I still cannot understand all clearly, I will always working on this recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- the `siunitx` package is missing
- the number of columns specified and actually in the table does not match
- the `S` column is missing instructions how to align the numbers
- to centre your vdots while the rest of the column is justified, you can use the `\makecell` macro from the package of the same name
- images are not math, don't put them in math mode

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} % Add
\usepackage{bbding} % Add
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{cellspace}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \caption{Text.}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} S[table-format=4.0] c X @{} }
    \toprule
        {Iterations} & Samples & Comments \\
    \midrule
        0     & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck} & Text is always being here\\
        32    & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck} & Text \\ 
        {$\vdots$} & $\vdots$ & \makecell[c]{$\vdots$} \\
        3200  & \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image-duck} & Text \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab4}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast and detailed reply! I only have one more question, why should we comment `\usepackage{cellspace}`, because if this, the gap between different rows is missing......

Comment: And is there any way to also left-align the "Samples"? If possible.

Comment: use an `l` column to left align them, but all your images have the same width, so it should not matter.